# JavaScript Combined with C# in Unity

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

can i code in ***JS***(JavaScript) and ***C#*** in unity together?

to make question more clear:
E.g:

> *i want to use C# for scripting the animations, but use JS For*
>   *Scripting Damage and Health.*

can i do that?

note: sorry for the wrong spelling English is not my first language

Comment: Unity only supports C#

Comment: I think it should be possible, but it seems like a bad idea :) Just have whoever wants to do javascript spend a morning looking into C# syntax. Since the concepts are the same, it should be an easy transition.
EDIT: Nevermind, [javascript isn't supported anymore!](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/08/11/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset/)

Comment: i looked into C#, i programmed in JS for 3 years, and i felt like its closer to Java than it is to JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Unity doesn't support Javascript since Unity 2017. If you are in an older version you can do it, however you must be sure that class containing the method to call is compiled before the one calling it. This is done by putting it first in the list.

Anyways, I don't recommend you to do so since it's against good practices to mix two languages in the same project.

Comment: thanks! turns out i was using unity since 2015 and ...... didn't update it